# Using regex in python call to API to clean up return

Tags: python, regex

The following Python Script:

```
def lookup(guildname):
    try:
        guildname = gw2api.get_guild_details(guildid)
        return guildname
    except:
        return''
```

Returns results that look like this: (each are single line)

```
{u'emblem': {u'foreground_secondary_color_id': 443, u'foreground_primary_color_id': 584, u'foreground_id': 107, u'background_id': 27, u'flags': [], u'background_color_id': 11}, u'guild_id': u'4FAEB34C-BA01-49C8-AD19-C651D69F9981', u'tag': u'RAWK', u'guild_name': u'Ready And Willing Knights'}
{u'emblem': {u'foreground_secondary_color_id': 443, u'foreground_primary_color_id': 11, u'foreground_id': 144, u'background_id': 22, u'flags': [u'FlipBackgroundHorizontal'], u'background_color_id': 4}, u'guild_id': u'DDE74A26-FC28-4514-926D-9BB590E6BDD2', u'tag': u'AI', u'guild_name': u'Alchemy Incorporated'}
{u'emblem': {u'foreground_secondary_color_id': 64, u'foreground_primary_color_id': 146, u'foreground_id': 148, u'background_id': 21, u'flags': [], u'background_color_id': 617}, u'guild_id': u'190E573E-8970-440E-8EA1-653098296EDB', u'tag': u'RoMS', u'guild_name': u'Roses Of The Moonlight Sigil'}
```

Using Regex I think I can get the guild name

```
([A-Z0-9a-z-]*\b [A-Z0-9a-z-]*)
```

But how do I apply that to the above python script? It needs to return just the unique guild name like `Roses Of The Moonlight Sigil` and `Alchemy Incorporated` instead of that huge big block. Not really sure if I have the right expression

Edit with proper function:

```
import json, gw2api

getguild = gw2api.get_servers()
guildapi = json.dumps(getguild)
apiresult = json.loads(guildapi)

print apiresult['name']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads), then access it as a normal dictionary. Regex is not needed:

```
import json
...
return json.loads(guildname)

thedict = the_one_returned
print thedict['guild_name']
# Prints Ready And Willing Knights
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), it'll safely convert those strings to a dict object and then you can fetch any key from that dict:

**Demo:**

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> strs = "{u'emblem': {u'foreground_secondary_color_id': 443, u'foreground_primary_color_id': 584, u'foreground_id': 107, u'background_id': 27, u'flags': [], u'background_color_id': 11}, u'guild_id': u'4FAEB34C-BA01-49C8-AD19-C651D69F9981', u'tag': u'RAWK', u'guild_name': u'Ready And Willing Knights'}"
>>> dic = literal_eval(strs)
>>> dic[u'guild_name']
u'Ready And Willing Knights'
```